# Is there a tool that will let me perform a search across multiple applications?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, wcf, search

I need to find all code references for a given SQL stored procedure. Our business has 8 Winforms applications and another 7 WCF services. We use VS2010.

I currently have to open each of these apps/services one-by-one and do a full solution search for the procedure that I am looking for. Is there a tool that will do this type of search?

It is a lot of manual work and automating this search would greatly speed up this process.

Comment: Find in Files works well. Windows built-in search also works well, especially if the source code locations are indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many many text search tools out there.

From the command line you can use 'grep' or 'find'.

In Visual Studio you can perform Solution-wide searches. Windows built-in search. Find in Files within Visual Studio, etc.

There is [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) as well.